# com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES - where is this symbolic reference's value set?

Tags: android

Having updated to the latest SDK 4.4W, SDK Tools 23.0 and Eclipse plugin 23.0, along with other IDE bugs, find that my projects refuse to build because of a build path error:

> The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library
>   C:\dev\tools\android-sdk-windows4.4\tools\support\annotations.jar'

I know that it's missing as that whole folder has gone and the jar now appears to be in this folder:

> C:\dev\tools\android-sdk-windows4.4\extras\android\support\annotations

My .classpath looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

I'm assuming that the last *.DEPENDENCIES* entry holds the explicit reference to the annotations.jar and I'm asking which file in the Eclipse or Android SDK or project folders contains that reference?

I'm hoping to 'poke' it temporarily  with the right reference until such time as Google get round to fixing this dreadful excuse for a release. (I don't want to create the old folder again and copy the new (bigger) annotations.jar into it)

Comment: I would assume those are values generated on the fly by the ADT plugin.

Comment: @CommonsWare - thanks, that would explain why I can't find them. Unpokable then, it's hard to believe they could have released this in its current state.

Comment: I can confirm that copying `extras/android/support/annotations/android-support-annotations.jar` to `tools/support/annotations.jar` works. I would expect that a hardlink or symlink would also work, though I have not tried this.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm CommonsWares answer, just copy the file and don´t forget to rename it to annotations.jar. This helped me